# Can I update multiple text layers simultaneously in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

First of all, I'm using Photoshop CS6. I'm also using a Mac, and don't have access to Windows. (if that makes any difference)

What I want to be able to do is have multiple text boxes containing the same text. The tough part is I want to be able to edit the text in one box, and the other(s) automatically change.

To clarify, I'm not looking to change the style, font or shape of the boxes. I want the actual text itself to be cloned across multiple boxes.

The scenario is that I am creating custom CD cases, and I want to be able to change text written on both spines at the same time, whilst only having to edit one entry.

I'm sure I found a guide to doing this a while ago, but a hour of 'Googling' has resulted in nothing useful. The guide I remember had the text change for the 'slave' boxes automatically, rather than having to select the layers and use the 'Find/Replace' option. I'm unsure if there was some kind of layer linking involved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as being able to do this would be a massive time saver.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the text layer -> Convert to Smart Object.

Duplicate that layer and place the other layers wherever else you want to display the same text.

To change text, double click the thumbnail (that will open a new window/tab where the text is in its own file) and change text, File -> Save when done. If you add more text than originally there you will have to expand the canvas size so the text is not clipped.